# Oozie workflow example failing despite running oozie-setup.sh sharelib with EJ001

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm trying to run the examples documented at https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.1/DG_Examples.html
When I run the first example it fails with EJ001:

```
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie# oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
job: 0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie# oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -info 0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Job ID : 0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : map-reduce-wf
App Path      : hdfs://localhost:20500/user/root/examples/apps/map-reduce/workflow.xml
Status        : FAILED
Run           : 0
User          : root
Group         : -
Created       : 2021-08-05 18:31 GMT
Started       : 2021-08-05 18:31 GMT
Last Modified : 2021-08-05 18:31 GMT
Ended         : 2021-08-05 18:31 GMT
CoordAction ID: -

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W@mr-node                                  FAILED    -                      -          EJ001     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie#
```

However the shared library has been installed and I ran oozie-setup.sh:

```
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie# /opt/oozie/bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:20500 -locallib /opt/oozie/oozie-sharelib-5.2.1.tar.gz 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Found Hadoop that does not support Erasure Coding. Not taking any action.
the destination path for sharelib is: /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805175137
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie# hdfs dfs -ls /user/root/share/lib
Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x  - root supergroup     0 2021-08-05 17:25 /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805172537
drwxr-xr-x  - root supergroup     0 2021-08-05 17:27 /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805172746
drwxr-xr-x  - root supergroup     0 2021-08-05 17:31 /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805173127
drwxr-xr-x  - root supergroup     0 2021-08-05 17:42 /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805174223
drwxr-xr-x  - root supergroup     0 2021-08-05 17:51 /user/root/share/lib/lib_20210805175137
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie# oozie admin -shareliblist
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[Available ShareLib]
root@50e1f53d5ded:/opt/oozie#
```

Please note above the output of oozie admin -shareliblist comes empty.

This is a snippet of the oozie-error.log:

```
2021-08-05 18:31:16,608  WARN ParameterVerifier:523 - SERVER[50e1f53d5ded] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] The application does not define formal parameters in its XML definition
2021-08-05 18:31:16,824  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[50e1f53d5ded] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [EJ001], Message [Could not locate Oozie sharelib]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: Could not locate Oozie sharelib
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addSystemShareLibForAction(JavaActionExecutor.java:671)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addAllShareLibs(JavaActionExecutor.java:817)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.setLibFilesArchives(JavaActionExecutor.java:776)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1051)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1644)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:243)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:68)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:290)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:363)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-08-05 18:31:16,825  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[50e1f53d5ded] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W@mr-node] Failing Job due to failed action [mr-node]
2021-08-05 18:31:16,828  WARN LiteWorkflowInstance:523 - SERVER[50e1f53d5ded] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000001-210805182256879-oozie-root-W@mr-node] Workflow Failed. Failing node [mr-node]
```

Any ideas of what am I missing here?